# Trying to understand example, determine fx and fy

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I´m trying to learn 2nd order Taylor but i cant understand the example i have.

This is an example i have from a book,

$$y´=\frac{y}{2}+x$$
$$-1\le x \le  1 $$
$$y(-1)=1$$

---

How does `fx = 1` and `fy = 1/2`?

$$f´(x,y)= fx+fyf = 1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y}{2}+x\right) = 1+\frac{y}{4}+\frac{x}{2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess $fx,fy$ mean:
$$f_x=\dfrac {\partial f}{ \partial x}=1$$
$$f_y=\dfrac {\partial f}{ \partial y}=\frac 12$$
Where $f(x,y)=\dfrac y 2 +x$.

So that you have:
$$\dfrac {df(x,y)}{dx}=\dfrac {\partial f}{ \partial x}+\dfrac {\partial f}{ \partial y}\dfrac {dy}{dx}=f_x+f_yf$$
$$\dfrac {df(x,y)}{dx}=1+\dfrac y 4+\dfrac x 2$$